# Error In trigger "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Order> at line 72 column 20"

Tags: triggercontext, before-trigger, trigger

```
trigger CreateOrder on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {
Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> OrderIds=new Set<Id>();
List <Order> OrderToInsert = new List <Order>(); 
Set<Id> quotepackageIds= new Set<Id>();
List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
List<Order> orderListNew = new List<Order>();
List<Quote_Package__c> qp=new List<Quote_Package__c>();
Map<Id,Id> OpportunityPricebook2=new Map<Id,Id>();
for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
if (o.StageName=='Won') {          
Order ord = new Order(); 
ord.AccountId= o.AccountId; 
ord.Status='Draft';
ord.opportunityid=o.id; 
ord.EffectiveDate=system.today(); 
ord.pricebook2id=o.pricebook2id;  
ord.CurrencyIsoCode=o.CurrencyIsoCode; 
OrderToInsert.add(ord); 
OrderIds.add(ord.id); 
opportunityIds.add(o.id);    
        }
insert OrderToInsert ; 
    }

for(Opportunity o1 : Trigger.old)
    {
if(o1.StageName=='Won')
        {
opportunityIds.add(o1.Id);
 }
}  

Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsWithLineItems = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Description,Quote_Package__c,Id,ListPrice,PriceBookEntryId,Name,OpportunityId,Product2Id,ProductCode,Quantity,TotalPrice,UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id IN :opportunityIds]);
if(opportunityIds.size() > 0)
    {
        // Loop through orders
        List<OrderItem> orderItemsForInsert = new List<OrderItem>();
        for(Order o : OrderToInsert)
        {
            // For each order get the related opportunity and line items, loop through the line items and add a new order line item to the order line item list for each matching opportunity line item
            Opportunity oppWithLineItem = oppsWithLineItems.get(o.OpportunityId);             
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : oppWithLineItem.OpportunityLineItems)
            {
                if(oli.Quote_Package__c!=null){

                quotepackageIds.add(oli.Quote_Package__c);

                }

           orderItemsForInsert.add(new OrderItem(Quantity=oli.Quantity,UnitPrice=oli.UnitPrice,PriceBookEntryId=oli.PriceBookEntryId,OrderId=o.Id));
            }
        }

        if(orderItemsForInsert.size() > 0)
        {
            insert orderItemsForInsert;
        }
        if(quotepackageIds.size()>0){

       qp=[SELECT Display_Price_As__c,Id,Name,OwnerId,Package__c,Physchem_Subpackage__c,Quote__c,SBU__c,SystemModstamp,Total_Price__c FROM Quote_Package__c where id in:quotepackageIds];

      }

   orderListNew =[SELECT AccountId,EffectiveDate,OpportunityId,OrderNumber,OriginalOrderId,Pricebook2Id,TotalAmount FROM Order where id in:OrderIds ];
    for (Quote_Package__c qop:qp){

      orderListNew =[SELECT AccountId,EffectiveDate,OpportunityId,OrderNumber,OriginalOrderId,Pricebook2Id,TotalAmount FROM Order where id in:OrderIds ];
      Order_Package__c ord =new Order_Package__c();
      ord.name=qop.name;
      ord.order__c=orderListNew.Id; //I am getting error on this line
      insert ord;
      }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone really wants to count to fond the 72'nd line.  Can you at least call out which line is throwing the error.  You might also want to add some context around the question as well.

Comment: I have commented in-front of that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your **orderListNew** Variable is a list type. You need to access through loop or provide index.

```
for (Quote_Package__c qop:qp){

      orderListNew =[SELECT AccountId,EffectiveDate,OpportunityId,OrderNumber,OriginalOrderId,Pricebook2Id,TotalAmount FROM Order where id in:OrderIds ];

      for(Order opc : orderListNew){

      Order_Package__c ord =new Order_Package__c();
      ord.name=qop.name;
      ord.order__c=opc.Id;//Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: at line 72 column 20 
}     
      insert ord;
      }
```

I also suggest you to keep your SOQL query out of loop statement to avoid 101 error.
Hope this will help.

Comment: It is showing Loop variable must be of type Order  in inner for loop

Comment: Sorry for the mistake... corrected the code check now.